# YouTube IFrame API: get video description

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

I need to fetch a video description (not a title) directly from a user's browser and the only legal that API provides is to call `player.getVideoData()` but it doesn't contain it.

I tried to use undocumented call to `https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id={video_id}` but it's blocked by CORS.

Also I found the API v3 [videos/list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) call that looks like
`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key=YOUR_API_KEY&part=snippet&id=VIDEO_ID`

But as I understood it's intended to Server to Server calls and I don't want to put my API key here.

From what I googled it looks like previously the `player.getVideoData()` returned the `description` but now it seems broken.

So is any way to get the description directly from browser?

Answer (score 0):

You can try read the description using `document.querySelector`- like:

```
document.querySelector("#description > yt-formatted-string").innerText
```

N.B. This `querySelector` worked for me even if YouTube website has in his URL parameter `disable_polymer=1`<sup>1</sup> or not.

or

```
document.querySelector("#eow-description").innerText
```

N.B: the last `querySelector` worked for me with old design. I recommend you use the first option, but have this `querySelector` just in case.

---

<sup>1</sup> add `disable_polymer=1` in the URL as a parameter for load YouTube's *old* design.